# Where does drush look for the path of the mysql socket (on MAMP)?

Tags: 8, drush

After upgrading from `drush 6.5.0` to `8.0.1-dev` through **brew**, the drush terminal command returns the popular

> 'PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]' error.

The only way to make it work is to add the unix_socket line to my Drupal `settings.php` files for all my projects:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'site',
      'username' => 'user',
      'password' => 'pass',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
      'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Even if I use `/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, it will work, because I have a symlink up:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    39B Mar 11  2015 /var/mysql/mysql.sock -> /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But that is exactly the thing I don't understand. And I would like to configure it at one point so I don't have to edit all the current and upcoming project's `settings.php` files.

So my question is: **Where does drush look for the path of the mysql socket (on MAMP)?**

If it's through the `php.ini`, it should be correct too (/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/conf/php.ini):

```
mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Currently, my `.bash_profile` contains no alias or export related to this issue because it worked fine with my previous drush installation.

Comment: use 'host' => '127.0.0.1' instead of localhost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, check which `php` and `php.ini` file is used by `drush`:

```
$ drush status --full
 Site URI                        :  http://default                                                                                                          
 Database driver                 :  mysql                                                                                                                   
 Database hostname               :  localhost                                                                                                               
 Database username               :  root                                                                                                                    
 Database name                   :  drupal7                                                                                                                  
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful                                                                                                              
 Drupal user                     :                                                                                                                          
 PHP executable                  :  /usr/local/opt/php56/bin/php                                                                                            
 PHP configuration               :  /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
```

Then edit its [default MySQL socket](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) name for local db connects:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/path/to/mysql.sock
```

as by default it points to `/tmp/mysql.sock` unless PHP was configured with different (`--with-mysql-sock`).

Check by:

```
$ php -i | grep ^pdo_mysql.default_socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /tmp/mysql.sock => /tmp/mysql.sock
```

So probably that's why `/var/mysql/mysql.sock` didn't work, as it was looking for `/tmp/mysql.sock` instead.

Then the symbolic link should work as expected.

If `drush` is using wrong instance of PHP, then add it into `PATH` (as you did) or specify with `--php=</path/to/file>`, so the right `php.ini` would be loaded.

Alternatively specify `unix_socket` in your settings file (as you already did).

Comment: probably /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini was used and indeed, pdo_mysql.default_socket was not even set there

Comment: As well as `drush status --full`, check `php -i` and look for "Additional .ini files parsed" - these are a common place to override settings in your main `php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution ...

```
drush status
```

shows the PHP executable path was the OSX native one, which was then symlinked to a PHP installed by brew

adding the following line to ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"
```

made drush look up into the correct php.ini file

but to me, it is still a mystery why the symlink

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    39B Mar 11  2015 /var/mysql/mysql.sock -> /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

did not do the trick